# VueJS how to do this kind of "for" loop: for(i = 0; i < x; i++)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm attempting to make a `for` loop like this in vue.js:

```
<div class="row" v-for="i = 0; i < numberOfRanking; i++">
   <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
     Rank 1
   </div>
   <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
     <input type="text" name="reward-sph-rank-1">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to generate dynamic fields where the user will select what ranking should be added. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an integer value to `v-for` in order to render a range of values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      numberOfRanking: 4,
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row" v-for="i in numberOfRanking">
    <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
      Rank {{ i }}
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
      <input type="text" :name="'reward-sph-rank-' + i">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's the documentation on `v-for`.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for)

Comment: Does `numberOfRanking` need to be an `Array` or can it be a `Number`?

Comment: It is needs to be a number.